# Linux box can't see the 802.11ac broadcast

Tags: linux, router, debian, wireless-router, 802.11ac

I have a TRENDnet TEW-824DRU with the latest DD-WRT on it. This unit has 2 interfaces that broadcast 2.4 and 5GHz respectively.

I also have a usb BrosTrend AC1200. I installed the drivers as explained below. After installing the device driver I can use it to connect to 2.4 ng mixed etc broadcast the Trendnet.

The problem is that I am not seeing the fast 5GHz connections at all. As far as I can tell our Samsung phones are able to pick up the broadcast but those are the only devices that are seeing the Trendnet's 5GHz interface connection.

I am using Debian Testing 64bit 4.3.0-1-amd64.

Is this an issue with the router, Linux or the usb adapter? I can't pinpoint the issue really. So I am looking for expert opinion to resolve it.

> ```
> Make sure you have the required build packages
> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
> Download the updated source code
>
> git clone https://github.com/scrivy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
> Compile the kernel module
>
> cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
> make
> Install it!
>
> sudo make install
> sudo modprobe 8812au
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that plugging the usb adapter to a usb2.0 port does limit this adapters connection options. I attached it to a usb 3.0 port then the 5ghz connection showed up.